# How can I send a url-encoded url as a parameter to mux?

Tags: go, mux

I have this code

```
func main() {
  router := mux.NewRouter()
  router.HandleFunc("/", rootHandler)
  router.HandleFunc("/xyz/{url}", urlHandler)
  http.Handle("/", router)

  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

With this url: `http://localhost:8080/xyz/https%3A%2F%2Fabc.no%2FJZ2las1o3Ct`
mux will redirect (301) to
`http://localhost:8080/xyz/https:/abc.no/JZ2las1o3Ct`

If I change `%2F%2F` to only one (`%2F`) I do not get redirected and the escaped characters stay escaped.

I have found references to `router.SkipClean(true)` but it makes no difference in how Mux handles this.

What I want is that the mux variable `url` should hold `https%3A%2F%2Fabc.no%2FJZ2las1o3Ct`

Comment: You could use a query parameter instead of a dynamic path segment.

Comment: Decode the url encoded parameter and use it in the mux for setting whole url

Comment: or if you want it to be a path segment, why don't you base64 encode it and decode it back?

Comment: Hello @vedhavyas I have also stated the same the url is already endcoded so we just have to decode it.

Comment: @mkopriva I am rewriting an existing service, so I can not change the path

Comment: @jim did you try this one? https://github.com/gorilla/mux/blob/master/mux.go#L216

Comment: ... and @jim make sure to call it before calling `router.HandleFunc(...`.

Comment: @mkopriva Yes.  I do not quite understand what it is for, but I tried it to make sure.  It makes no difference in this situation.  I tried it both before and after the HandleFunc(...

Comment: @jim It means that it will use the escaped path instead of an unescaped one which is what you want because the unescaped one will get cleaned up, resulting in the redirect. Keep in mind though, that the `UseEncodedPath` behaviour takes effect only when skipClean is false. So, as far as I understand, you have to either call `SkipClean` or `UseEncodedPath` *before* registering the handler but not both. If you've tried that and it didn't work then I don't know what else.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks. That clarified the usage of UseEncodedPath.  But it still is redirected :(   I have tried both `UseEncodedPath()` and `SkipClean(true)` again (placed before HandleFunc) with no luck. I even used different ports to make sure that caching was not a issue.  But thanks for the help!

Comment: I ran into this the other day and didn't find a solution. I ended up stuffing the URL into a query parameter.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for here is the `UseEncodedPath` setting.

https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router.UseEncodedPath

The default behaviour in mux is to decode the URL, then do the path matching.

If you turn on UseEncodedPath, it won't decode the path parameter and when you access the path param inside your handler it will still be encoded.

At that point you can choose if you want to decode the parameter or not using the go `QueryUnescape` function.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `QueryUnescape` for removing the spaces and other url coded paramters.
Please look for the [function](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#QueryUnescape)

https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#QueryUnescape

Comment: How can I unescape a part of the path of an url before the mux router handles it?

Comment: you can first parse the url and use it as query parameter rather than part of url handled by mux. You to unescape it separatel first by splitting the url and then use it.

Comment: But how can I parse the url before the router has found a hit? The point of a router is to determine what function should handle a path.

Comment: use mux subrouting. Can't split the string when encounter with second http and then parse it and attach it again in mux